# Why Can't I acces to function ? ag-grid Angular2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am in detailCellRendererParams, I am trying acces to function checkNumber into the template but I get error `Cannot read property 'checkNumber' of undefined`, And If I try join the template, I can't declarate in template...

```
this.detailCellRendererParams = {
     detailGridOptions: {},
     checkNumber(data) {
        console.log('into');
        if (!Number.isInteger(data.value)) {
           return 0;
        }
      },    
      template: function(params) {
          let number = 1;
          number =  this.checkNumber(number);
          return ( '<p>' + number + '</p>' );
     }
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per question your code seems written in wrong format , it should be like this -

```
this.detailCellRendererParams = {
  detailGridOptions: { },
  template: (params) => {
      let number = 1;
      number =  this.checkNumber(number);
      return ( '<p>' + number + '</p>' );
    }
}

checkNumber(data) {
  console.log('into');
  if (!Number.isInteger(data.value)) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CheckNumber` looks like utility function , suggest you to write function in other file and export it and make it available as utility function

```
export function  checkNumber(data) {
            console.log('into');
            if (!Number.isInteger(data.value)) {
              return 0;
            }
          }
```

and then import this function directly in you componet.ts file where you are using your ag-grid

```
import { checkNumber} from '@shared/utility-functions';

     template: function(params) {
               let number = 1;
               number =  checkNumber(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function for `template` definition as show in below code.

```
template: (params) => {
    let number = 1;
    number = this.checkNumber(number);

    return ('<p>' + number + '</p>');
}
```

The reason why you are not able to get `checkNumber` inside `template` function is that its not able to get the same scope. When you use `arrow function` as above, it will be able to get it.